# php registration validation which stops showing form on no errors and success

Tags: php, mysql, isset

```
<?php
//Form Validation
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
        //Must be at least 4-15 characters and contain letters and numbers
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,15}$/', $_POST['username']))
        {
            $error[]='The username does not match the requirements';        
        }
        //Password validation: must contain at least 1 letter and number. Allows characters !@#$% and be 6-15 characters
        if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,15}$/', $_POST['password1']))
        {
            $error[]='The password does not match the requirements';
        }
        //Email validation
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $error[]='Invalid E-mail';
        }       
        //Output error in array as each line
        foreach ($error as $output)
        {
            echo "$output <br>";
        }
}
if ((empty($errors)) && !isset($_POST['register']))
{
?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="register">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" maxlength="15" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>" /><br>
    <input type="password" maxlength="15" name="password1" /><br>
    <input type="password" maxlength="15" name="password2" /><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" maxlength="25"  name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>"/><br>
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="county" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register"/>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Hi all,

I have got to the point where it doesn't show errors but I probably didn't explain myself too clearly. After the point at which it doesn't show error messages anymore, I would like the form to no longer appear and then I can put something down like "Successful." However I can't seem to achieve this.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for help with? You just talked about what it is you want to accomplish?

Comment: The if statements are all incorrect for the output. The error message shows initially, which it shouldn't.

Comment: What do you mean by, 'The error message shows initially'? Do you mean the error message is shown at the top of the form, and you want it at the bottom?

Comment: Well, it shows there is an invalid e-mail address etc even before you have pressed submit

Comment: Change `if(!isset($_POST['register']))` to `if(isset($_POST['register']))` and see if that works.

Comment: I have already majorly changed it around. I have now got it so it doesn't show the error right away and does after, but I still can't make it so it no longer shows the form when there is no errors :'(

Comment: The answer below is what I wanted. Form doesn't show when there aren't any errors, and the words "Success" come up instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$sent = false;

if ( isset($_POST['register']) ) 
    {
        $error = array();

        //Must be at least 4-15 characters and contain letters and numbers
        if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,15}$/', $_POST['username']))
        {
            $error[]='The username does not match the requirements';        
        }
        //Password validation: must contain at least 1 letter and number. Allows characters !@#$% and be 6-15 characters
        if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,15}$/', $_POST['password1']))
        {
            $error[]='The password does not match the requirements';
        }
        //Email validation
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $error[]='Invalid E-mail';
        }       

        if ( count($error) > 0) 
        {
            foreach ($error as $output) {
               echo "{$output} <br>";
            }
        } else {
            $sent = true;
        }
    }//end isset register

?>

<?php if ($sent==false) { ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="register">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" maxlength="15" name="username" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) {echo $_POST['username'];} ?>" /><br>
        <input type="password" maxlength="15" name="password1" /><br>
        <input type="password" maxlength="15" name="password2" /><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" maxlength="25"  name="email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) {echo $_POST['email'];} ?>"/><br>
        <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="county" /><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register"/>
    </form>

<?php } else { echo "Success!"; } ?>
```

Comment: This would still show the form though? I have revised my topic, if you could please have another look at what I mean, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have updated it check again. It's fairly easy to understand the logic!

Comment: Beautiful sir! I guess I couldn't do it without that extra bit of code you added, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. That extra code is a way to hide the form if it is submitted without errors. So I used a variable `$sent` to know when it is. If `$sent` is `true`, the script will hide the form, else it will show it! Initially, `$sent` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to have a form where you accept input from users and display errors until all of them are fixed. Your idea is fine, but there are some logical errors in your code.

Here's how it works:

- Display the form first
- Accept user input
- Do the checks for email and password
- If there are any errors, display them

These are the changes I've made in your code:

- Removed the `if(empty($errors))`. It's unnecessary
- Changed `if(!isset($_POST['register']))` to `if(isset($_POST['register']))` -- we want to display the form if it wasn't submitted.
- Added `isset` checks inside the `<input` fields to make sure they're only displayed if the variables are defined
- Removed the last code block for `}` as it's no longer needed

Try this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $error = array(); //initializing an empty array

    //Must be at least 4-15 characters and contain letters and numbers
    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,15}$/', $_POST['username']))
    {
        $error[]='The username does not match the requirements';        
    }
    //Password validation: must contain at least 1 letter and number. Allows characters !@#$% and be 6-15 characters
    if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,15}$/', $_POST['password1']))
    {
        $error[]='The password does not match the requirements';
    }
    //Email validation
    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $error[]='Invalid E-mail';
    }       
    //Output error in array as each line
    foreach ($error as $output)
    {
        if(isset($output)) {
            echo "$output <br>";
        }
    }

}
    if(!isset($error)) {
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" name="register">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" maxlength="15" name="username" 
    value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username']; ?>" /><br>
    <input type="password" maxlength="15" name="password1" /><br>
    <input type="password" maxlength="15" name="password2" /><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="your@email.com" maxlength="25"  name="email" 
    value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>"/><br>
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="county" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="register"/>
</form>

<?php

} 

else {
    echo "Successful";
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, this is partly it but once there is no errors I want to remove the form entirely and then put "successful" or something down.

Comment: @user2784248: Sure, it's possible to do that. You can just add an `if(empty($error)) { // echo message }` after your foreach loop.

Comment: @user2784248: I've edited the answer and included a more cleaner version to accomplish the same. Check it out ;-)

Comment: Hi, I tried it but when you type in something in a field, it just doesn't show the table anymore but the errors are still showing. I don't know if its possible to do it without adding another variable in like Nikos has done.